# How do I go back now?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, iso

last day I installed Ubuntu 16.04 On a brand new hp 14 ap-000 series. I have wiped away the whole harddisk and I only have Ubuntu on it now. But I really need to go back to WIndows 10. But I don't have any recovery image or Iso file, how can I go back now? I asked my friend to crate an recovery image on his Windows 10 pc, so, how can I use this to go back?

Comment: Do you want to install Windows alongside Ubuntu?

Comment: maybe, I just want Windows back!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call Microsoft and ask them if they can help you seeing this is a new machine they should be able to supply you with a recovery disk. I'm not sure if there would be a fee but I would think since you are a customer they would help you ether way

I also found this link to Microsoft's website were you might be able to download a ISO file to reinstall Windows 10, [Windows 10 download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/)

Answer (score 0):

Until you can get windows back:
Oracle virtual box: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
and the free developers edition of  windows 10: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/
will allow you to run windows until HP or Microsoft can get you an official version to solve your issue